# CreateFont API quality

Tags: c++, windows, gdi, photoshop

So I'm trying to using `CreateFont` to try to create a font similar to the one I have in Photoshop, but if you look close the quality in Photoshop is a lot better.

Here's the code I'm using to create the font:

```
CreateFont(45, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, FF_MODERN, __T("Times New Roman"));
```

And here is a comparison of the two fonts:

[image: Fonts]

As you can see the top one is much smoother.
Should I be using different arguments in `CreateFont`? I'll admit I don't completely understand them all.
An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop uses its own antialiasing and applies it consistently.

Windows only uses antialiasing on font sizes within certain limits, and it looks like your sample is outside the limits. Here's a quote from the [`CreateFont` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499.aspx) (emphasis added):

> ANTIALIASED_QUALITY Font is antialiased, or smoothed, if the font supports it and the **size of the font is not too small or too large**.

You might have better control in GDI+.

Comment: Alright, so is there any way to set a control to draw with GDI+ font? `WM_SETFONT` only accepts `HFONT`s so would I have to owner draw it? Or is there some trick to this.

Comment: @Josh, you're right, the only way to use GDI+ is to do owner draw. And looking closer at the sample, Windows is actually antialiasing the font, it's just doing a much worse job than Photoshop.